# Nested Lambda functions

Tags: c++, function, lambda, nested

In my program I want to have the following structure:

```
for ( int counter=0 ; counter<K ; ++counter )
{
  some code..

  // Lambda function definition of inner function - something like
  auto outerFunction = [&] std::function< std::function<void()> innerFunctionOp )
  {
      // Lambda function algorithm body
      ..
      ..

      auto innerFunctionA = [&]()  { code block }
      auto innerFunctionB = [&]()  { code block }
      ..
      ..
      // Next call the passed lambda
      innerFunctionOp();
   }

   // and now for the outer lambda activation
   outerFunction( innerFunctionA ); 
}
```

When trying to do that, the call for `outerFunction( innerLambdaFunction )` doesn't pass compilation for what seem to be the following reasons:

1. the inner functions seem not to be visible from the outside (makes sense)
2. Due to the above, the initialization of the outer lambda is missing.

It makes sense that the inner functions are not visible from the outset calling level, and so, how do I solve this issue?

Comment: It really depends on what the code does on how it can be refactored.  Can we get a complete [mre] so we can advise on how to refactor?

Comment: Why are you keeping the compiler error message secret from us?

Comment: This line `auto outerFunction = [&] std::function< std::function<void()> innerFunctionOp )` is clearly invalid. Please provide [mcve] prefreably using one of online sites: https://godbolt.org/ https://wandbox.org/ https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ or other.

Comment: If this is some version of Visual Studio please copy the error messages from the Output tab not the Errors List. The output tab is usually a longer format and is better for copy / paste since its in a line format and not broken into a list format.

Comment: My personal rules for "clean code" says never use nested lambdas. In fact when I use lambda their body is one line (only in rare cases 3 lines tops). This makes code readable and there is no problem with complex error messages. I recommend to solve your problem by applying this rule to your code.

Comment: to @MarekR - tnx for the tip, I am indeed now running testes on this.  The benefit is that your suggestion leads to clear code, however at the same time it also takes some of the power I was expecting from Lambda since now I need to pass variable list that before was not required :(



For the rest requesting the compiler errors - you are right, but as I am putting out this question, my code already went through 4 different variations to try and solve it in parallel, hence I put out the general question and if there is an expert out there that can teach us all, great!

Comment: Lambdas are just syntactic sugar for functor objects.  When I get confused by lambdas, I write them out "long hand" as classes with `operator()` functors.  Usually I can see my flaw, and wrap them back up as lambdas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply declare your functions side by side:

```
for ( int counter=0 ; counter<K ; ++counter )
{

   auto innerFunctionA = [&]()  { /* ... */ };
   auto innerFunctionB = [&]()  { /* ... */ };

   // Lambda function definition of inner function - something like
   auto outerFunction = [&](auto innerFunctionOp )
   {
       innerFunctionOp();
   }

   // and now for the outer lambda activation
   outerFunction( innerFunctionA ); 
}
```

If the inner lambda capture local variables, then pass the variables as parameters:

```
for ( int counter=0 ; counter<K ; ++counter )
{

   auto innerFunctionA = [](int a, double b)  { /* ... */ };
   auto innerFunctionB = [](int a, double b)  { /* ... */ };

   // Lambda function definition of inner function - something like
   auto outerFunction = [&](auto innerFunctionOp )
   {
       int result_a = /* ... */;
       double result_b = /* ... */;
       innerFunctionOp(result_a, result_b);
   }

   // and now for the outer lambda activation
   outerFunction( innerFunctionA ); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this seems to work nicely
My two concerns are that I seem not to be able to do something like: 

outerFunction( count ? innerFunctionA : innerFunctionB );

in this case the compiler reports the following error: 

error C2446: ':': no conversion from 'ClassFunctionName::lambda_b6733f69484712cfa>' to 'ClassFunctionName::<lambda_dedbca16ca51f82d42>'

And:

note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Well, I solved this with an if, but that takes me even further from keeping it 'lambda clean code'

Comment: @Adi: `innerFunctionA` and `innerFunctionB` have unrelated types, so you cannot have `cond ? innerFunctionA  : innerFunctionB`. You might type erase the lambdas inside `std::function` though.

Comment: @Adi you can put the condition a bit sooner in the expression: `count ?  outerFunction(innerFunctionA) : outerFunction(innerFunctionB)`